# Django: Finding out which table in inheritance hierarchy has the field

Tags: django, inheritance, model, field

Consider the following example:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField()
class Derived(Base):
    pass
```

Now, the base and derived classes will have different tables in the databases.

My question is how to find out which table myfield belongs to?

Comment: Some docs on Django i found while searching for the answer: http://django-model-internals-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/get_all_field_names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_meta.get_fields_with_model()` method:

```
for field, model in Derived._meta.get_fields_with_model():
    if field.name == 'myfield':
        model = model or Derived
        print 'myfield belongs to %s' % model._meta.db_table
```